# Xml stylesheet doesn't work because of namespace

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I want to get the fullname of the following so the result should be "Root Administratoren"

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
 <GetAllGroupsOfUserResponse xmlns="http://fuu/fuu/fuu/">
  <GetAllGroupsOfUserResult>
   <Group>
    <DataId>11</DataId>
    <ObjectGuid>31ea4ee1-cf85-44ac-846e-6ef58542af2c</ObjectGuid>
    <FullName>Root Administratoren</FullName>
   </Group>
  </GetAllGroupsOfUserResult>
 </GetAllGroupsOfUserResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

I am using this XML-Stylesheet

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:tmp="http://tempuri.org/">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Result>
   <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfGroup/Group">
   <FullName>
    <xsl:value-of select="FullName" />
   </FullName>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i get no result when I delete the namespace it works but the xml has to stay this way.
Thank your for your help

Greetings
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new prefix for the default namespace, and use it, with each element in your XPath.
Also, add in a // to get all ArrayOfGroup elements.

```html
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:tmp="http://tempuri.org/"
xmlns:fuu="http://fuu/fuu/fuu/"
>
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Result>
   <xsl:for-each select="//fuu:ArrayOfGroup/fuu:Group">
   <FullName>
    <xsl:value-of select="fuu:FullName" />
   </FullName>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```